# java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner

Tags: java, multithreading

I get `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner` on `notify` when I try to print "1a2b3c..." even `flag.nofity()` is in the syncrhonized block.
However, if I use another object to synchronize and notify, it works as expected.
Can someone explain why?

```
class Main{
    static volatile Boolean flag = true;
    static int cnt = 26;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 1; i <= cnt; i++) {
                synchronized (flag) {
                    try {
                        while(!flag) flag.wait();
                        System.out.print(i);
                        flag = false;
                        flag.notify();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
                synchronized (flag) {
                    try {
                        while(flag) flag.wait();
                        System.out.print((char) (i + 'a'));
                        flag = true;
                        flag.notify();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

A working example

```
class Main{
    static volatile Boolean flag = true;
    static Object obj = new Object();
    static int cnt = 26;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 1; i <= cnt; i++) {
                synchronized (obj) {
                    try {
                        while(!flag) obj.wait();
                        System.out.print(i);
                        flag = false;
                        obj.notify();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
                synchronized (obj) {
                    try {
                        while(flag) obj.wait();
                        System.out.print((char) (i + 'a'));
                        flag = true;
                        obj.notify();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say `flag` is `Boolean.TRUE` to start an iteration of the loop. So, this:

```
synchronized (flag) {
```

will acquire the lock on `Boolean.TRUE`. Then, in the first thread, you do:

```
flag = false;
flag.notify();
```

This means you're trying to call `notify` on `Boolean.FALSE`, even though you never acquired the lock for that object. A similar thing happens in the second loop, just with `TRUE` and `FALSE` switched.

Your working example succeeds because you never re-assign `obj`, meaning that each thread always calls `notify()` on the same object that it locked on within the `synchronized` statement.

More generally, acquiring a lock on a mutable variable is problematic. For example, this would let you have two threads enter the `synchronized` block at the same time: one enters it by locking on `TRUE`, and the other enters it by locking on `FALSE`. That's almost always a bug (the whole reason you have the `synchronized` is to prevent multiple threads from entering the block at the same time!), and when it *is* what you want, a higher-level abstraction like [`java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) is clearer and easier to use in a bug-free way.